# How do elite athletes benefit from training (almost) every day?

Tags: rest

If rest is so important, why do elite athletes train every or almost every day, and some of them even multiple times a day?

I'm assuming in many sports, athletes will train every day and still be among the best in the world. How is that possible? I understand some of them are in an extraordinary shape but why wouldn't the "rest is important" rule apply to them as well? And especially to them if they're looking to squeeze out absolutely everything that's in their body to train themselves to be the best at what they do.

I understand some sports are combination of some kind of technique combined with strength/endurance but still.. Top MMA fighters, football player, rowers, gymnasts, swimmers, runners, I assume all the people at the top probably train every day.

PS - wasn't sure if this should perhaps be in the [sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com).. if yes, please move the question over there.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What amount of training/rest/food you need to accomplish your goals, isn't the same for everyone. There's no one-size-fits-all plan that says "do these exercises, sleep x hours, and eat these exact foods", which will work for any and all.

When we hear of athletes training every single day, it tells us this: They rest enough throughout the rest of the day (no pun intended), and they eat the appropriate amount of food. It's not farfetched to think that whatever amount of time they spend training, the rest of the day is pure resting and eating.

The fact that they are in amazing shape does contribute indirectly, in that the years and years they've spent training has prepared their bodies for this stress. Their bodies have simply learned to thrive in this routine.

> I understand some of them are in an extraordinary shape but why wouldn't the "rest is important" rule apply to them as well?

It absolutely does apply. And they've spent lots of time finding out exactly what amount of training they can do daily, while still getting enough time and food to recover completely.

It's likely that in the course of calibrating, they've had periods where they suffered from chronic fatigue due to too much training, and too little rest, and stepped it down a few notches in order to find their personal ideal ratio.